# Not able to retrieve value from radiobutton (returns NULL)

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, struts

I have got a couple of radiobuttons of which I need to retrieve the value in order to filter some search results. But the problem is I only seem to get 'NULL' values returned from the `valueRadio` object in the action.

What is it that I'm missing/overlooking? Please let me know if you need more information.

---

The .JSP page

```
...
<c:set var="filter" value="${PageData.fields.filter}" />
<html-el:form action="/myResultPage" styleId="myResultPage-form" method="get">
    ...
    <div class="form-block floatstop">
        <html-el:radio property="field(filter.correct)" value="1"/>
        <label>Show only correct results</label>
        <br><br>
        <html-el:radio property="field(filter.correct)" value=""/>
       <label>Show only incorrect results</label>                                           
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="floatstop">
    <p class="formbuttonwrapper left">
        <span class="left" style="margin-left: 10px;">
            <em class="block left">
                <html-el:button property="event(filterResults)" styleId="searchButton" styleClass="pointer formbuttonwrapper greenButton">Search</html-el:button>
             </em>
        </span>
     </p>
    ...
   </div>
   ...
</html-el:form>
...
```

Javascript

```
...    
function addSearchClickListener()
{
    $("#searchButton").click(function()
    {
        if($('#myResultPage-form').valid())
        {
            var values =
            {   
                'someValue' : $("#someValue").val(),
                ... //retrieving all values to be shown in the list          
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: contextPath + "/myResultPage.do",
                type: "get",
                cache: false,
                data: 
                {
                    "event(filterResults)": "",
                    "field(fieldsJSON)": JSON.stringify(values)
                },
                success: function(data, status, request)
                {
                    //create list of results
                    //show list
                },
                error: function(data) 
                {
                    ...
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
...
```

The action

```
public ActionForward onGetFilterResults(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
    ...
    PageData inForm = ActionUtils.getInputForm(mapping, request, form);
    String fieldsJSON = (String)inForm.getField("fieldsJSON");
    Map<String,Object> fields = (Map<String,Object>)(new JSONReader()).read(fieldsJSON);
    ResultVo resultVo = new ResultVo();
    ...
    Object valueRadio = fields.get("correct");
    if(valueRadio != null && ((String)valueRadio).length() != 0)
    {
        if(Integer.parseInt((String)valueRadio ) == 1)
        {
            resultVo.setResult_incorrect(0); //0 = correct values, 1 = incorrect values
        }
        else
        {
            resultVo.setResult_incorrect(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
         resultVo.setResult_incorrect(1);
    }
   ...
}
```

---

In the debug logs the following all return 'NULL' no matter which button is selected.

```
    LOGGER.debug("valueRadio : " + valueRadio );
    LOGGER.debug("get fields: " + fields.get("correct"));
    LOGGER.debug("get fields: " + fields.get("filter.correct"));
    LOGGER.debug("get field: " + inForm.getField("correct"));
    LOGGER.debug("get field: " + inForm.getField("filter.correct"));
    LOGGER.debug("request parameter: " + request.getParameter("correct"));
    LOGGER.debug("request parameter: " + request.getParameter("filter.correct"));
    LOGGER.debug("request paramValues: " + request.paramValues("correct"));
    LOGGER.debug("request paramValues: " + request.paramValues("filter.correct"));
```

Also have I tried to adress the radiobuttons as such:

```
("correct[0]") & ("correct[1]")
```

---

### EDIT

The radiobuttons used to be 1 checkbox (showing a list of the correct results when checked). The `valueRadio` object was then named `valueCheckbox` and `fields.get("correct")` did return `1` when the checkbox was checked.

This was the checkbox:

```
...
<div class="form-block floatstop">
    <html-el:checkbox property="field(filter.correct)" styleId="correct" value="1"/>
    <label>Show only correct results</label>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Please don't write "solved" into the question title. Accept the correct answer is all you need to do, then the problem was solved. (since you answered your own question, you may need to wait a certain amount of time, before you can accept it)

Comment: @Tom I temporarily added  'solved' to the question because I still had to wait > 20 hours before I could accept my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a stupid mistake, I didn't notice I forgot the `styleId`, by which the input fields inside the `<html-el:form/>` are adressed by the JavaScript.

With `styleId="correct"` added to the radio button the `fields.get("correct")` returns 1 when the radio button is checked, as it should.

```
<html-el:radio property="field(filter.correct)" styleId="correct" value="1"/>
```

---

*I haven't tried adding `styleId="correct"` to both radiobuttons as for this application the value of only 1 of the buttons is needed.*